# Error of unused argument when I am binding four dataframes using do.call and rbind

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge four dataframes I had obtained earlier using the same `rbind` function:

```
EU_dist <- do.call("rbind",
                   EU_dist_objects_list)

WB_dist <- do.call("rbind",
                   WB_dist_objects_list)

WB_MDTF_dist <- do.call("rbind",
                   WB_MDTF_dist_objects_list)

NL_dist <- do.call("rbind",
                   NL_dist_objects_list)
```

So I want to combine the four dataframes using the line below:

`ALL_dist <- do.call("rbind",WB_dist,NL_dist,WB_MDTF_dist,EU_dist)`

> Error in do.call("rbind", WB_dist, NL_dist, WB_MDTF_dist, EU_dist) : 
>     unused argument (EU_dist)

Just to make sure EU_dist didn't have any issues, I have put at the end other WB, NL, or WB_MDTF _dist and I am always getting the error of unused argument (Last argument in the order of arguments in.

Any insight as to the cause of error and how I can change it will be highly appreciated

Comment: `do.call("rbind", list(WB_dist,NL_dist,WB_MDTF_dist,EU_dist))`

Comment: Thanks, when I implement that correction, I get the error `Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied`. What is, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Looks like your four data.frames don't have exactly the same columns with exactly the same classes?